# Can't access app variable in Slim route?

Tags: php, slim

This is probably pretty basic for Slim, or maybe even a php issue, but I have no idea why it's not working:

```
$body = $app->request->getBody();
syslog(LOG_INFO,$body);

$app->put('/contacts',function(){
        try {
            $body = $app->request->getBody();
            syslog(LOG_INFO,"contacts received: ".json_decode($body));
        } catch(Exception $ex){
            syslog(LOG_ERR,$ex);
        }
    });
```

The first log gets the body, but when i get to the second one i get this error:

> exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Undefined variable: app'

same thing happens when I try commenting out the one in the put request and try to read the $body

> exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Undefined variable: body'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to pass it in like this:

```
$app->put('/get-connections',function() use ($app) {
```

Why this is not obvious in the documentation I do not know.

Comment: Check "Application Names and Scopes" in the [documentation](http://docs.slimframework.com/).